# executing a php script with variables arguments in AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, background

I would like to be able to execute a php script on a onclick state, but each page could hace multiple buttons each with a different action to send. I want the script to be executed, but i don't want the page tobe changed.

This is to execute a UDP client to change setting in a remote box.each button send a different action to different board, in fact i need to send 2 arguments to the script.

something like this i need to send: set_states.php?ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx&cmd=CR1

Thanx for the help!

Comment: Just find an ajax tutorial, there are a lot on the net.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter what the URL is. The important things is what HTML verb you are using (get, post, delete, put) and your returned content type. The URL can be anything. I'd just use some js library like jquery. Check out their $.get, $.post, $.ajax functions.

If you don't use a js library then you need to account for all the differences in various browsers. Typically though it goes something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

In your case, I would use jquery (since it'll get you started extremely quickly). Since your variables are in the url and you aren't sending any other data you would use get. Typically for mutators you should use post. I don't think it matters in your case. Drop the following script on to your webpage (make changes as needed):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#the-id-of-your-button').live('click',function(){
        $.get('set_states.php?ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx&cmd=CR1',function(return){
           alert('success');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The first part:  `$('#the-id-of-your-button').live('click'` watches the browser in a sense to see if any elements that match appear and binds a click event to them. Live actively awaits for dom changes in a sense. Click is the handler, and $('#the-id-of-your-button') is the selector. The next part:

```
function(){
        $.get('set_states.php?ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx&cmd=CR1',function(return){
               alert('success');
        });
    });
```

is what happens when the click event occurs. We call this an anonymous function. It can be rewritten as:

```
function onButtonClick(){
        $.get('set_states.php?ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx&cmd=CR1',function(return){
               alert('success');
        });
    });
    $('#the-id-of-your-button').live('click',onButtonClick());
```

or something like that, but thats just just to help you understand what is going on.

The next part:

```
$.get('set_states.php?ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx&cmd=CR1',function(return){
           alert('success');
    });
```

is the ajax request and the function to execute if it successfully returns. In this case it will simply just alert us.

Oh also: `$(function(){});` that wraps everything up, tells us to run the script when the page is ready. Soooo once the page is ready we will turn on the live command to watch for buttons. You may not need it (I know there are some cases, where it isn't important, but I put it there just in case).

You may need to tweak it a bit :).

Comment: To be honest i am totally new to AJAX, the script i want to execute will have no output at all. So i don`t know what is the best to use?

Comment: Ahh, ok, so a quick rule of thumb, almost anytime you have a function/script that acts like a mutator (in that it modifies something but doesn't necessarily return anything) it should be done using a post. Get implies that you are retrieving data.

You should use post, and for that matter you should use jquery since it is extremely easy. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Parris You should review your answer ... URL is most important in an ajax request, jquery is not a framework , it's a library .